# soap request with password in the body

Tags: php, security, soap

two days ago i've heard about soap and since then i've successfully communicated with the server. But i am not familiar with the SOAP protocol

My app will transfer sensitive data to the server, that said i've been wondering if the method the creators of the main app use, is safe enough:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetArtigoRef xmlns="http://www.*********.com:**/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <referencia>string</referencia>
    </GetArtigoRef>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

As you may notice, the username and password are located as plain text in the first two fields , and moreover pretty well identified.

I am not using any type of encryption while sending the data through php and soapcall.

What can i expect from this? Any worries to have or can i chill?

Thank you very much for your enlightenments!
Cheers to all.

Comment: It sounds like the people who own the server don't have their crap together. Sending passwords in plaintext over the internet is never a good idea. Contact their development team and see if they are working on TLS/SSL (https) for their SOAP service.

Answer (score 0):

If you call SOAP by httpS it is enough security.

Comment: I don't have an SSL protocol. This is why i would like to know if they could solve the problem. Could they fix this on their side?

Comment: If you request SOAP by plain http you vulnerable to attack man-in-the middle. If it's possible — ask admin of remote server to enable SSL.

Comment: Even though an SSL certificate isn't that expensive, i think i can get the same type of security by hashing the salted password. A nice way would be with them creating a token to use as salt. Or i could simply use a standard salt....

Comment: If you can modify remote server it can be many things to do. But hashing password isn't the case. Because remote server can't 'unhash' it. Because hashing is not irreversible operation.
You need to use encryption instead.

Comment: If their application will accept hashed or hashed+salted passwords and that hash will be stolen that cause same result — authorising by that hashed/salted string as plain password.

Comment: One good thing about the token is that they can create one at my request, and use it only once. 
This is why i talked about the token, if they create one token to serve as salt, this means it can be used only once. Even if they steal it, when they try to use again the same salted, it won't do.

Comment: You can use SSL without paid certificate search the web by keyword "self singed certificate". It's much simpler for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

If i may say so, I think that is the standard when it comes to soap servers. I would be more concerned about the http, rather than http**s** . That would be one thing i'd change.

Secondly, this has more to do with the server you are connecting to. Imagine you send the server a pre-salted password, and then it salts that :) Could do for some interesting testing.

To the best of my knowledge, that is how it works, even with LDAP and other soap deployments. Password is always sent in plaintext =\

Perhaps someone can advise a more secure way of communicating with the server.

Comment: Well, if their application could accept salted passwords, i could salt it before sending it. Even something basic as md5 would make this more secure. This way, it sounds far too easy to get busted. Someone listening to the network could get this information with not much effort. They could provide a way to call a TOKEN and i could salt it and hash it with SHA.

Answer (score 0):

The server that handles these messages MUST use SSL.  And they MUST have a real certificate, not a self-signed one.  In addition, their web server must be configured to disallow outdated protocols (see OWASP-CM-001).  Otherwise you are vulnerable to all sorts of nastiness.

This is industry standard and shouldn't be a big deal.  SSL is absolutely mandatory for secure handling of credentials.